# HTML Element/Div is narrowing in response to decreased screen width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I am working on a responsive design that breaks when the screen is narrower than approx. 380 px. The issue seems to be that the whole HTML page element is narrowing and dragging the child elements and making the whole page out of centre ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRXnf.png)). I have tried to experiment with break-points to fix this however I can't seem to make the HTML element of the page stay at a 100% width when going into very small screen sizes.

I have a feeling I am missing something fundamental so any help in pointing this out would be helpful!

My code: https://github.com/thomaswalsh92/wordsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .dashboard class you set gap to 1rem. Gap property is shorthand for column-gap and row-gap. Because of column-gap was set to 1rem your page was out of centre. You should also consider changing fixed width on your .x class on smaller screens. After this fixes your layout isn't breaking.

1. [Link to Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-lake-zm21f)
2. [MDN - Gap property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

```css
.dashboard {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr) [21];
  grid-template-columns: repeat(21, 1fr);
  -ms-grid-rows: (minmax(32px, auto)) [3];
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, minmax(32px, auto));
  gap: 1rem 0;
}

.word-board-section .word-board-container .x {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Replaced the gap with margin-bottom for the elements in the grid section and got this working correctly, thanks for the help!